# cypher get relation properties from path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query that goes like this :

```
start n=node(15) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n return p;
```

The result given are :

(1)--[OWES,484]-->(3)--[OWES,494]-->(1)

(1)--[OWES,484]-->(3)--[OWES,494]-->(1)--[OWES,483]-->(2)--[OWES,487]-->(1)

(1)--[OWES,483]-->(2)--[OWES,488]-->(3)--[OWES,494]-->(1)

(1)--[OWES,483]-->(2)--[OWES,487]-->(1)

(1)--[OWES,483]-->(2)--[OWES,487]-->(1)--[OWES,484]-->(3)--[OWES,494]-->(1)

My relation OWES has property 'amount' which say how much does one node owes to other , how do I get the relation property from path , I can not say return r.amount (!?) .

Answer (score 1):

I got it like this :

```
start n=node(15) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n return extract(s in relationships(p) : s.amount),extract(t in nodes(p) : t.taxnumber)
```

Comment: How can I now make sure that 1 does not repeat in between like I have in : (1)--[OWES,484]-->(3)--[OWES,494]-->(1)--[OWES,483]-->(2)--[OWES,487]-->(1)

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about repeating.

Comment: Hellow, base on the official site that's extract was deprecated.
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-extract

And of course, I Get error when i implement it. How to get the property from relations in the path by other ways..?